# Correct usage of the word "wages" and what the word is describing

Tags: grammatical-number

> "The glory is yours to claim, for that is the wages of war."

The above line feels so natural to me, but someone pointed out they thought it would be grammatically correct to use one of the below options, all of which just sound odd to me:

> "The glory is yours to claim, for those are the wages of war."

Doesn't sound right to me because "those" isn't the word I would use to refer to "glory."

> "The glory is yours to claim, for that is the wage of war."

Also somehow sounds wrong when I think about all of the ways I hear the word...

> "The wages of sin is death."

and I've never heard anybody say *"...a day's wage."* It's always *"...a day's wages."*

Also, I'm a little biased because this is for a script for a board game I am designing, called "Wages of War."

Is the first sentence really incorrect? Nobody I showed this to said anything about this until after I got the voice-over recorded, unfortunately.
Knowing that this is the title of the game, is that justifiable reason to leave it being that it's really a play on the title?

Comment: How does ***"The glory is the wages of war"*** sound to you?

Comment: "The glory is yours to claim: the wages of war." avoids what I consider a jarring juxtaposition. 'The wages of sin is death' certainly seems to license singular agreement with 'wages', but the usage is archaic.

Comment: *Wage* can certainly be singular: [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/wage) has "an income of less than half the average wage". In your sentence, *that* is referring to *glory,* which is singular and takes *is,* as @Hank has commented.

Comment: @Tom22: I don't think it's really that "wages of war" is an "idiom" (in respect of being treated as a singular noun phrase). Note that MW says (for the sense [recompense, reward](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wage)) *usually used in pl. but **singular or plural** in construction **the wages of sin is death***.

Comment: There used to be a billboard on the Beltway in Eugene, Oregon that proclaimed, **"The wages of sin is death."** The singular verb ("is") always bothered me. I knew it was a quote from the Bible, and a quick check just now of my early 1634/1632 King James Version indeed reads, "*Romanes Chap. VI 23 For the wages of sinne is death; but the gift of God is eternall life, through Jesus Christ our Lord.*" Why "wages"? Wouldn't "the cost" (or "the price") of sin is death make more sense? Wages are payment for labor, not payment for sin. And, it seems to me that death is not a "wage." Curious.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, would it help to know that the context/game is a medieval theme? (To address the fact that it's an archaic use of the word?)

Comment: I can't speak for Edwin, but I think the "antiquity" of the board game you've developed would warrant the use of "The glory is yours to claim, for that is the wages of war." Speaking of antiquities (if you remember DOS), see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quest_for_Glory_III:_Wages_of_War :-)

Comment: Just a thought: perhaps you can avoid the issue altogether by adding a second wage of war: "The glory and x are yours to claim, for those are the wages of war"

Answer (score 1):

In a case like this, normal usage had best determine how to proceed.
Usage suggests that "wages" refers to "complete compensation" while "wage" refers to "salary". This seems common usage: *wage earner* (one who earns a salary), *top wages*, (high on the scale of compensation).
It may be the popularity of the KJV quote *The wages of sin is death* may have kept the plural form in the language long after it could have been abandoned, except to indicate more than one individual salary, and settled this question. That quote seems to have put in the English speaker's mind something beyond simple monetary reward for "wages". We can have a "wage scale", but probably not a "wages scale". We can write *He has a low wage job* and not sound unusual. But *He has a low wages job* does sound odd.
There just does not seem any reason to change "The glory is yours to claim, for that is the wages of war.". According to general usage, it is fine.

Comment: But this doesn't address the singular agreement of the plural-form.

Comment: The precedent of the KJV Bible seems to completely deal with the question of number.. The translators of that Bible must have considered "wages" as a collective.

Comment: There are _verily_'s, _thee_'s and _thou_'s in the KJV also, but that doesn't mean that we should use them today and hope to sound normal.

Comment: That is quite right. However the older pronouns rarely are part of an entrenched idiomatic expression such as "The wages of sin is death".. The ancestors that created this expression cannot defend it. I cannot defend it, and would not if I could. But I can accept it as part of our language.

Comment: "The wages of sin is death" scores getting on for half a million hits on Google. "That is the wages of war"  scores zero (apart from the single example here). The former is the fixed expression; the latter is a non-standard echo.

Comment: I agree it is an echo.. It is an echo of a very establish precedent..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52402/discussion-between-j-taylor-and-edwin-ashworth).